# assigning variable to kendo ui filter

Tags: kendo-ui

I couldn't able to assign the variable to datasource filter. What am I missing?

var selectVal = "Test";

```
    var wcDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport : { read : function(data) {
            $http.get(restUrls.GET_OPR
                    .replace('?', '100')
                    .replace('?', '251')
                    .replace('?', '211'))
            .then(function(response) {  
                data.success(response.data.workCenter); 
                console.log("selected value:  "+selectVal); //outputs 'Test'
            }, function(error) {
                swal("Error!", "Error while fetching!", "error");
            });
            }
        },
        filter: {
            filters: [
                {field: "cc", operator: "eq", value: selectVal} // selectVal doesn't read here
            ]
        }
    });
```

Please anyone let me know, what am I missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to receive the filters you have to enable 
serverFiltering: true in your data source options.

this will give you the filter in the options.data property :)

```
  var dataSource = kendo.data.DataSource.create({
        transport: {
            read: function(options) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/read',
                    data: options.data,
                    success: function(result) {
                        options.success(result);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        // do what you want.
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        serverFiltering: true, //<-- important
        filter: {
            filters: [{
                operator: 'eq',
                field: 'Name',
                value: 'David'
            }]
        }
    });

    dataSource.read();
```

Comment: Hi David, Sorry for the delayed reply. Thank you very much for the solution provided.

Comment: If it answers your question please mark as answer :)